# How to get first unique character in a string after a string search?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to find if a user enters a username in the content of their post on my new social network. For example: "Happy birthday to @drew he's so cool". I want to be able to search the string for "@", and then 'take apart' the string to get the value of the username. I basically want to end with "@drew".

```
var n = contentq.search("@");
var newname = contentq.splice(n, /no idea/ )
```

This is honestly what I have so far. I figured the best way was to find the "@", and then splice the text from the @ to the index of the first space (" "). My question is, how do I get the index of the first space after "@"? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using a regex to find the @ and text following it up to the space

```
var text = "Hello @drew how are you doing?";

function getUserName(text){
    var parsed = /(@.*?)\s/.exec(text);
    if(parsed){
        return parsed[1];
    }
}

console.log(getUserName(text)); //Prints @drew
```

Edit: This won't catch "Hello @drew" because of the space. Jagsparrows `\w+` would do better

```
var text = "Hello @drew how are you doing?";

function getUserName(text){
    var parsed = /(@\w+)/.exec(text);
    if(parsed){
        return parsed[1];
    }
}

console.log(getUserName(text)); //Prints @drew
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Gabs00 Yes, I apologize. My account is still fairly new, and I had to wait some time before I could accept your answer

Answer (score 2):

Search for `@` then for `word` regex.

```
var str = "Happy birthday to @drew he's so cool"
str.match(/@\w+/)
```